Why incorrect syntax on Transaction Builder on SAFE wallet web interface (smart contract wallet)
Using the transaction builder to do test a swap on Uniswap
contract: 0x2626664c2603336E57B271c5C0b26F421741e481
I selected: "exactInputSingle"
I entered as the tuple this code:
{
"tokenIn": "0x8d285Df5bE4570097E84241090FCa8034AB18547",
"tokenOut": "0x833589fCD6eDb6E08f4c7C32D4f71b54bdA02913",
"fee": 3000,
"recipient": "myaddress",
"amountIn": "5000000000000000",
"amountOutMinimum": "17670000",
"sqrtPriceLimitX96": "0"
}
The interface shows:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
I tried a few different syntax for the code, expliciting tuple or params and nothing worked.
Thanks

This seems to be a problem linked to the Transactions builder in Safe{Wallet}. I suggest you visit help.safe.global and contact the dedicated support team, by clicking on the message icon at the bottom right of the page and explain the problem to them.
This stack exchange tag (safe-core) is more intended to be used for developers having trouble building on top of Safe{Core}.
Hope it helps! Best, Louis
